# dot2tex does not draw shapes like "doublecircle"

Tags: tikz-pgf, dot2tex

I was following a [tutorial](https://wiki.vis.ethz.ch/LaTeX#Endliche_Automaten_in_DOT_language_in_LaTeX) to try adding a dot graph to latex. I don't understand the dot code in-depth, I just copy pasted it, but I think it is not displaying as intended in the final pdf.

**Dot Code**

```
digraph simpleFA
{
    rankdir=LR;
    node [shape="point"] start;
    node [shape="circle"] p0;
    node [shape="circle"] p1;
    node [shape="doublecircle"] p2;
 
    start -> p0;
 
    p0 -> p0 [label="0"];
    p0 -> p1 [label="1"];
 
    p1 -> p2 [label="0"];
    p1 -> p1 [label="1"];
 
    p2 -> p2 [label="0,1"];
}
```

I'm working with cygwin and MikTex on Windows. Ran a `pip install dot2tex` in cygwin. I then executed `dot2tex -o temp.tex --prog dot temp.dot` (any options other than `dot` gave only worse results).

**Resulting LaTex Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
%

%

%

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%
%
%

\enlargethispage{100cm}
% Start of code
% \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=mid,>=latex',line join=bevel,]
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',line join=bevel,]
  \pgfsetlinewidth{1bp}
%%
\pgfsetcolor{black}
  % Edge: p2 -> p2
  \draw [->] (223.22bp,47.126bp) .. controls (222.45bp,57.406bp) and (225.15bp,66.296bp)  .. (231.34bp,66.296bp) .. controls (235.3bp,66.296bp) and (237.84bp,62.648bp)  .. (239.46bp,47.126bp);
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (231.34bp,73.796bp) node {0,1};
  % Edge: p1 -> p1
  \draw [->] (136.85bp,42.991bp) .. controls (135.63bp,53.093bp) and (138.03bp,62.296bp)  .. (144.04bp,62.296bp) .. controls (147.9bp,62.296bp) and (150.27bp,58.519bp)  .. (151.24bp,42.991bp);
  \draw (144.04bp,69.796bp) node {1};
  % Edge: p1 -> p2
  \draw [->] (164.29bp,24.148bp) .. controls (173.99bp,24.148bp) and (185.87bp,24.148bp)  .. (207.17bp,24.148bp);
  \draw (185.69bp,31.648bp) node {0};
  % Edge: start -> p0
  \draw [->] (3.7613bp,24.148bp) .. controls (8.1357bp,24.148bp) and (19.192bp,24.148bp)  .. (40.58bp,24.148bp);
  % Edge: p0 -> p1
  \draw [->] (80.912bp,24.148bp) .. controls (90.763bp,24.148bp) and (102.82bp,24.148bp)  .. (123.78bp,24.148bp);
  \draw (102.4bp,31.648bp) node {1};
  % Edge: p0 -> p0
  \draw [->] (53.874bp,43.384bp) .. controls (52.816bp,53.331bp) and (55.108bp,62.296bp)  .. (60.748bp,62.296bp) .. controls (64.274bp,62.296bp) and (66.491bp,58.794bp)  .. (67.623bp,43.384bp);
  \draw (60.748bp,69.796bp) node {0};
  % Node: p2
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (231.34bp,24.148bp) node {p2};
\end{scope}
  % Node: start
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \definecolor{fillcol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetfillcolor{fillcol}
\end{scope}
  % Node: p0
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (60.748bp,24.148bp) node {p0};
\end{scope}
  % Node: p1
\begin{scope}
  \definecolor{strokecol}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.0};
  \pgfsetstrokecolor{strokecol}
  \draw (144.04bp,24.148bp) node {p1};
\end{scope}
%
\end{tikzpicture}
% End of code

%
\end{document}
%
```

It seems to me that the shapes for the nodes didn't make it into the LaTex code because I cannot find anything that looks like code for a circle to me.
Compiling this code with TexWorks (pdftex+MakeIndex+BibTex, the default option) results in this graph:
[image: graph]

**I would have expected some circles and doublecircles around the nodes.** How can I fix this?

I have tried:

- A clean install of MikTex
- A different computer, but also with Cygwin, Windows 10, MikTex
- Using the `--figonly` flag
- Using different `--prog` options

I believe I have all relevant packages installed. These I had to install are:

- xcolor
- pgf
- pgftools

**Possible Solution / Workaround**
Running `dot -Tps temp.dot -o temp.ps` and opening the ps file in Adobe Acrobat Distiller produces the graph as expected.[image: graph as expected]

Or, better: `dot -Tpng temp.dot -o temp.png` to get the graphic directly.

That doesn't feel like a real solution though - I don't understand quite enough what's going on, but I assume `dot2tex` is supposed to work.

*I am looking for a fix, rather than a different way of doing that*, though I'm sure alternative ways will also be useful for future visitors.

Comment: this simple graph is far more simple draw direct in `tikz`. and it will work as expected.

Comment: Confirm the code produces the expected result in `graphviz`, and `dot2tex` is also unsuccessful on my Linux machine. Either you do it in `tikz` or, since you have the `dot` code already, integrate the graphics into your LaTeX document.

Comment: a guess: remove " " from your shape specifications.

Comment: @Ross Good Idea! Just tried it. The changed version still works with `dot` and still gives the same unexpected result with `dot2tex` though

Comment: Looks like it is a known bug: https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex/issues/44.

Comment: @Ross Thanks so much for your help! :) I wrote an answer but in case you want the rep, I feel like you deserve it. I'll accept your answer if you write one (otherwise I'll probably accept my own)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Looks like it is a known bug:
>   https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex/issues/44
>   - [Ross](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410131/dot2tex-does-not-draw-shapes-like-doublecircle?noredirect=1#comment1023893_410131)

And in that link:

> <sub>expbbc commented on 29 Dec 2016</sub>
>
> This was fixed in 2014 here: [914f805](https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex/commit/914f8051e7a64ef118d2cb7a355b0011ec15f970)
>   Kjellmf has never bothered to push an updated version to pip.

Turns out the latest version available [on Github](https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex) is up-to-date (currently version `2.10.dev`) while the version on `pip` is still at version `2.9.0` from 2014.

So, for anyone else with the same problem...

### The Fix

Firstly, uninstall the old version that you got from pip.

```
pip uninstall dot2tex
```

Then, navigate to some directory where you want to download the new version to and fetch the files. This will create a new directory `dot2tex`

```
git clone https://github.com/kjellmf/dot2tex.git
```

Now install it again.

```
cd dot2tex
python setup.py install
```

In my case, it added dot2tex automatically to the path environment variable, so it works now.

```
dot2tex --prog dot -o temp.tex temp.dot
```

And the output now contains lines like `\draw (60.75bp,24.15bp) ellipse (20.3bp and 20.3bp);`. The compiled Latex pdf matches the output of `dot`.

Answer (score 4):

It is very simple to do with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, border =30pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{pst-node}
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % to compile with pdflatex --enable-write 18 (MiKTeX)) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, Mac TeX)

\begin{document}

\small
\psset{arrowinset=0, linejoin=1,shortput=nab,linejoin = 1}
\def\pscolhookii{\hspace{-0.2cm}}%
\def\pscolhookiv{\psset{doubleline, doublesep = 2pt}}
$ \begin{psmatrix}[mnode =circle, colsep = 0.8cm, emnode = dot]
 & [name = p0] p_0 & [name = p1] p_1 & [name = p2] p_2
\psset{arrows = ->, doubleline = false}
\foreach \s/\t in {{1,1}/p0, p0/p1, p1/p2}{\ncline{\s}{\t}}
\psset{angleA = 65, angleB = 115, ncurv = 5, arrows = <-}
\foreach \p/\label in {p0/0,p1/1,p2/0.1}{\nccurve{\p}{\p}\nbput{\label}}
    \end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

with `tikz` is also very simple:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, chains, quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance = 12mm,
        start chain = going right,
state/.append style = {on chain, join=by -latex},
               auto = left
                    ]
\coordinate[on chain] (in);
\node (p0) [state] {$p_0$};
\node (p1) [state] {$p_1$};
\node (p2) [state,double] {$p_2$};
\fill (in) circle (1pt);
\draw[->]   (p0) edge [loop above,"0" ] ()
            (p1) edge [loop above,"2"]  ()
            (p2) edge [loop above,"0.1"] ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]